# Mysql: What is 'AUTO_INCREMENT=5' in a create table query?

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have a create table query in which there is a last clause which says `AUTO_INCREMENT=5`

Could someone explain what does that mean? below is the sample create table MySQL query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `uploaderdata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mdn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `service_request_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `carrier` varchar(160) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CHT',
  `firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `alt_contactnumber` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `document_files` longblob NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `casenumber` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dated` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fetched` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The auto_increment value of the first record starts with `5` instead of the default `1`.

The `id` has an ongoing number for each record that starts from 5.

Answer (score 4):

read the documentation first.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, you can set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

the table already has 4 records , so the next record being inserted will take the value in AUTOINCREMENT field which is id in your case as 5